# Apache PdfBox library in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, ant, pdfbox, ikvm

I want to use Apache's PDFBox Library in C#, i checked on NuGet but sadly, there's no PDFBox 2.0 in there.

I searched the internet for ways to use the Java Library on .Net, found some old articles (2011-2014) saying that i should use IKVM, and found some newer articles saying that IKVM is no longer updated and that it doesn't work no more.

Is there any working way to make the PDFBox 2.0 library work with C#?

I apologize if my questions sounds stupid, but 2 hours ago i didn't knew that we could convert Java libraries to .NET lol.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on what you need to do there are some other alternatives

https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig is a Port of PdfBox to .NET, but it's an early version.

PdfSharp is another alternative that I have used a bit

IText is another alternative which is free to use if you are using it for yourself

Comment: Actually, i needed a while ago and i couldn't use ITextSharp because it was for a company where i was Intern. Going to check PdfPig and PdfSharp. Thanks